# Graph of the equation of the form P(x,y)=Q(x,y)

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose

$$x^2 + y^2 = 4-eqn(1)$$

is any equation. If we plot this equation on a graph paper with the usual meaning of $x,y$ we will get some shape such that each point in the shape is the solution set of the above equation. Now I multiply both side of the equation by the term $x^3$. So the new equation is $$x^5 + y^2x^5 = 4x^3-eqn(2)$$ This represents another shape. The point of this shape includes the point of previous equation $+$ some additional points,say $k = (a,b)$.

Now I rewrite my eqn(2) as $x^3(x^2 + y^2) = 4x^3$. I see this forces $k$ to solve $x^2+y^2=4$ as I can always cancel the $x^3$ term if its non-zero. So my final conculsion is the shape of the graph of both the equation will be same which is sounds absurd to me because the degree of eqn(1) is 1 ( in both x and y) and deg of eqn(2) is 5 and 2 for x and y respectively. So where is my reasoning going wrong. This was just one example, In general when I multiply by a variable on both LHS and RHS and hence increase the degree won't it change the set of solution and hence the graph.

Comment: The solutions $k$ are introduced by the factors you introduced. If you cancel the factors, the $k$ are no longer solutions. For example, $(0,0)$ is not a solution to $x^2+y^2=1$, but it is a solution to $x^3+xy^2=x$. If I then divide both sides by $x$, I recover the original equation, and of course $(0,0)$ is not a solution to it.

Comment: So in general suppose their exist an eqn which already has (0,0) as its solution, then the graph will look same even when i increase the degree.

Comment: @ManishKumarSingh Not necesarily. If you multiply the equation by $(x-1)$, you added $(1,y)$ to the set of solutions...

Comment: Unfortunately, we can't see what $eqn(1)$ is, but I assume that it is not the case that all points $(0,y)$ are solutions of your original equation. After you multiply both sides by $x^3$ (or even just $x$), the vertical line $x=0$ is part of the solution set. So you probably have introduced extra solutions (your $k$'s). In the example in my comment above, the graph of the first equation is a circle, while the graph of the second equation is the union of a circle and a vertical line.